How to convert a dynamic MBR disk to basic GPT?
Widows 10 is nagging me to upgrade to Windows 11 before support ends. I can't do that because my boot disk is MBR, not GPT. It is also a dynamic disk, so this might be a 2 step operation.
How do I convert it to GPT, without backing up a reformatting, and without paying money?  I have read all related questions, but none seem to have my problem with the dynamic disk

Does the disk have any spanned volumes (i.e. consisting of several disjoint parts)? Depending on that, conversion might be either very easy or outright impossible.

Going from Dynamic to basic is only possibly by removing all partitions. Not sure you can go from MBR to GPT without removing all partitions either.

You'd want to back it up anyway - disk conversion is a little dangerous.

@LPChip there are tools to convert MBR to GPT without losing data, and there's also a built-in tool in Windows for that. There are also some 3rd party partitioning tools that can convert dynamic to basic without losing data

I went through this very same exercise a while back. I know you're chasing a free solution (I was too), but doing this without data loss or installed program loss is the very reason that I know own a paid copy of EaseUS Partition Master Professional. This worked seamlessly for me.
Of course, have a crack at the free ones first, the ones I tried failed for me (luckily gracefully):
https://www.tomsguide.com/how-to/how-to-convert-mbr-to-gpt-partition-on-windows-11
https://www.thewindowsclub.com/convert-mbr-to-gpt-disk

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
